# Install git via homebrew on mac osx 10.10 results in: Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2

Tags: macos, git, github, homebrew

Hi I just tried installing git via homebrew on my mac - something is wrong. I had the github for mac app installed, but I tried removing that. The current git version in my system is:

```
Nielsk@~: $ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

This is what happens if I try to install git via homebrew:

```
Nielsk@~: $ brew install git
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.1.3.y
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Pouring git-2.1.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you do the install as an elevated user using `sudo brew install git`

Comment: Why would I do sudo with brew, that's not really the idea is it?

Comment: When I commented on the question I was thinking Macports, you are correct with Homebrew - the usage of `sudo` isn't even supported

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I also met the same issue. I think we should change the readable permission to make sure any of the directories is readable by "all". So I tried the command: `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local`
and then: `brew link --overwrite git` It works for me, hope it will also work for you.

Comment: @NielsKristian : You likely had something (non-Homebrew) previously installed to /usr/local or at some point you ran commands with sudo that wrote to /usr/local . Modifying the permissions is what you should do and what the Homebrew installer does. There is a major thread about this in the Homebrew `issues` page that you can find [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953#issuecomment-3800557) . Mike McQuaid a maintainer of homebrew makes it clear that the changing of /usr/local privs is the preferred way. You will see him suggest a similar change to permissions as Jonyzfu.

Comment: @Jonyzfu although your command is okay, I think your reasoning is wrong.`sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local` doesn't make everything in `/usr/local` readable by all. The '-R' means `recursive`.What this command does do is alter the `user` and `group` so that the $USER  in question and the group `admin` are owners. `$USER` is a variable that holds the name of the user you logged in as when you run the command. If you aren't a member of `admin` group or the user you ran your command with you may find yourself with restrictive readw/rite privs depending on the actual directory/file permissions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for your explanation in detail. It's helpful. I will provide my answer in more detail and more accurately next time, just like your attitude.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I just hit the same permission issue on brand new Macbook Pro (Yosemite 10.10.2). I didn't have anything else installed to `/usr/local` at all.

Comment: Also had the same issue on a brand new install of El Capitan and I didn't install anything before. But it seems to have worked.

Comment: I had the same issue with NPM and this solved it athough you remember to change brew link --overwrite git to brew link --overwrite npm

Comment: On MacOS 10.13 I have got errror: 

chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 9):

From High Sierra, `chown` of `/usr/local` is not allowed. However you can still change permission the sub directories in `/usr/local`.

In my case, I had to create `Frameworks` in `/usr/local` and `sudo chown -R $(whom) Frameworks`. After that follow what `brew doctor` says.

The better way is to create subdirectory whatever you need and run

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Answer (score 8):

For those with the new El Capitan OS, you'll need to update your permissions:

Open Terminal and type the following commands:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local 
$ brew doctor 
$ brew update
$ brew link --overwrite git
```

The above solution will work for other brew installs like node, etc.  Just replace the last line if you started the installation but encountered errors during the brew installation.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar `permission denied` error on install of `git` until I cleaned things up:

```
$brew doctor
   .....   << long output of issues, so you run:
$brew prune
$brew doctor
   .....   << less issues now, so manually clean up
$brew update 
$brew install git
```

Does that address your error as well?

Answer (score 0):

I did what `brew doctor` recommended and it helped:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin
```

MacOS 10.14.4